# magento 2 bundle product with dynamic pricing

Tags: magento2

My Question is about 
**Is super attribute pricing applicable for bundle product?** Because I want to set dynamic price for all combination.

Comment: Maybe research on https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I saw this site but there were no solution for this

Comment: But since there is a site dedicated to Magneto, my suggestion is to use it. If you can craft a question that satisfies their requirements (it will have to have more details than you provide here, though) then that is still the best place